# Does it make sense to talk about $ O(z)$ if $z$ complex?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Does it make sense to talk about $ O(z)$ if $z$ complex? I would have thought that the usual definition wouldn't hold, since doesn't the fact that we don't have an order on $\mathbb{C}$ change things? Do we have to talk about $O(|z|)$ instead?

For instance, could we say that
$$
Az^2 + Bz = O(|z|)
$$
for $A, B, z \in \mathbb{C}$, in the same way that we would say that it is $O(z)$ if we were just working in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Not really, because the $O$ notation is defined in terms of less than, i.e., numerical order, which is a concept alien to complex numbers.

Comment: Everything you said seems reasonable to me. $O(|z|)$ makes sense; $O(z)$ does not, for exactly the reason that you said.

Comment: @RonGordon. So would an expression like the one in the question be $O(z)$? How would we put a bound on it? -- as in, talk about relative accuracy/how it behaves $\to 0$?

Comment: I think the best explanation about "Big-O" notation is in deBruijn's book on asymptotic analysis.  Barring that, here's a nice, if lengthy, discussion:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: You want something that says "the limit of f over g goes to zero."  The problem is in defining "small" and "large" for complex variables.  That's why we need the absolute values.

Answer (score 3):

> Does it make sense to talk about $O(z)$ if $z$ complex?

It depends on how you define $O$. Here are the two slightly different definitions:

1. $f(x) = O\bigl( g(x)\bigr)\iff \exists\ C > 0\ \exists\ x_0 > 0\ \forall\ x > x_0: |f(x)| \le C\cdot g(x)$
2. $f(x) = O\bigl( g(x)\bigr)\iff \exists\ C > 0\ \exists\ x_0 > 0\ \forall\ x > x_0: |f(x)| \le C\cdot|g(x)|.$

Note that the difference here is about $g$ is embedded in absolute value signs or not. If we let $g$ be a complex valued function, the first definition doesn't make sense for non-positive functions, since the complex numbers are not ordered, whereas the latter definition works for all functions.

**History**

The symbol $O$ was first introduced by number theorist Paul Bachmann in 1894, in the second volume of his book [Analytische Zahlentheorie](https://archive.org/details/dieanalytischeza00bachuoft/page/401/mode/1up). The number theorist Edmund Landau adopted it and [defined it more rigorously](https://archive.org/details/handbuchderlehre01landuoft/page/60/mode/1up). So the historical definition is 1. since at the time there was no need to define $O$ for negative or complex functions.

**Today**

Now there is no leading definition. I looked at a few Wikipedia articles: [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition), [German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau-Symbole#Definition), [French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparaison_asymptotique#D%C3%A9finition_formelle_2), [Spanish](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cota_superior_asint%C3%B3tica), [Italian](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/O-grande#Definizione_formale), [Portuguese](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grande-O#Defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o_Formal) and [Russian](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%ABO%C2%BB_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%C2%ABo%C2%BB_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B5#%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

All articles, except the English one, use the second definition.

**Solution**

If you are writing a paper, you may define the Big-$O$ notation you are using in the preliminaries. The other possibility is to always write the absolute value, which makes both definitions equivalent.

Comment: Your English is very neat and clean : there's literally one place where I think you missed an article or something. I just edited this to be absolutely sure, but I think it was great previously as well. Also liked the little history section, I had no clue! I always thought Knuth had invented the notation, turns out it was older!